# React router v5 useHistory.push goes without params

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using router-dom V5 and when i try to navigate to another page with some params it goes without the params. But when I click the back button on the browser, it shows the correct URL.

```
    let navigate = useHistory ();
    
    const handleChecked = async(e) => {
      let isChecked = e.target.checked;
      if(isChecked){
        seatSelected.push(e.target.name)
      } else {
        seatSelected = seatSelected.filter((name) => e.target.name !== name);
      }
      setChecked(!checked);
      console.log(seatSelected)
    }
    
    const proceedHandleClicked = () => {
        if(seatSelected.length > 0){
            navigate.push({
            pathname:'/eventbookingsummary',
            search: `?seats=${seatSelected}`,
            })
            seatSelected = []
        } else {
            alert('Please select seats')
        }
    }
    return(
   <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} onClick={proceedHandleClicke}>
                                    Proceed
                                </Link>
                            <div className='checkbox-container'>
                            <input id='T1' name='T1' type='checkbox'  onChange={(e) =>handleChecked(e)} 
                            className='table-seats'/>
                            <label htmlFor='T1' className='btn'>T1</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className='checkbox-container'>
                            <input id='T2' name='T2' type='checkbox'  onChange={(e) =>handleChecked(e)} 
                            className='table-seats'/>
                            <label htmlFor='T2' className='btn'>T2</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className='checkbox-container'>
                            <input id='T3' name='T3' type='checkbox'  onChange={(e) =>handleChecked(e)} 
                            className='table-seats'/>
                            <label htmlFor='T3' className='btn'>T3</label>
                            </div>
)
```

[image: when proceedHandleClicked]
when proceedHandleClicked initially
[image: after back button clicked]
after back button clicked

Comment: What are the screenshots trying to convey? It looks like the URL path and queryString is `"/eventbookingsummary?seats=T2,T3"`. It's a bit unclear what the issue may be.

Comment: when i click the handle it navigate to the next screen without params. but when I clicked the back button it shows the correct URL with params

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example ([mcve]) so we can have better context? If possible do you think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: here your state is not updating for the first time that's why it's happening.

Comment: @Kantivekariya can you suggest an answer?

Comment: can u pls provide more details so I can help in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that the `Link` component is missing the `to` prop, and the `proceedHandleClicked` doesn't prevent the default link action from occurring. Two navigation actions are issued. The first is the `navigate.push` ***then*** the link action. When you navigate back once you see the URL with the query params.

Add a `to` prop to the `Link` and consume the click event and prevent the default link action from occurring.

Example:

```
const proceedHandleClicked = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (seatSelected.length > 0) {
    navigate.push({
      pathname: "/eventbookingsummary",
      search: `?seats=${seatSelected}`
    });
    seatSelected = [];
  } else {
    alert("Please select seats");
  }
};

...

<Link
  to="/eventbookingsummary"
  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
  onClick={proceedHandleClicked}
>
  Proceed
</Link>
```

[image: Edit react-router-listen-to-push-requests]

Answer (score 0):

You can set your search param like this:

```
 navigate.push({
        pathname: '/eventbookingsummary',
        search: `?seats=${seatSelected.toString()}`, 
    })
```